# How to perform a Django ORM calculation across a submodel

Tags: django, orm

I'm trying to figure out how to get a specific clients percentage share of income which may be split between multiple owners or shared equally. The models (simplified) are:

```
class Client(Model):
   ...

class Loan(Model):
    applicants = ManyToManyField(Client)

class Income(Model):
    loan = ForeignKey(Loan)
    amount = DecimalField()
    income_type = CharField(choices=['INVESTMENT', ...])
    proportions = CharField(default='EQUAL', choices=['EQUAL', 'SPECIFIED'])

class IncomeOwner(Model):
    income = ForeignKey(Income, related_name='owners')
    client = ForeignKey(Client)
    percent = DecimalField()
```

From those models I'm attempting the following to calculate income shares, by category, for a given client/loan combination. It's important to note that the owners relation only matters if proportions is 'SPECIFIED' - otherwise all applicants have an equal share. For performance reasons I'm trying to keep the logic in the ORM:

```
def get_income(loan, client):
    # This income can be associated with multiple applicants as follows:
    # - If the "proportions" are "EQUAL" then assign this applicant an equal split
    #   between the other applicants (amount / num_applicants)
    # - Otherwise use the amount directly assigned to the income owner

    # The percentage based on number of applicants or taken from the owner percent field
    equal_share_percent = ExpressionWrapper(100 / F('num_applicants'), output_field=PercentageValueField())
    applicant_share_percent = Case(
        When(proportions='SPECIFIED', then=F('owners__percent')), <-- ONLY WANT % FOR THIS CLIENT
        default=equal_share_percent
    )
    # Total amount applicant receives
    applicant_amount = ExpressionWrapper(
        F('applicant_percent') / 100 * F('amount'), output_field=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    )
    
    loan_income_summary = Income.objects.filter(
        loan=loan
    ).annotate(
        # number of people with a share of the income
        num_applicants=Count('applicants', output_field=models.IntegerField()),
    ).annotate(
        # applicant's percentage share
        applicant_percent=applicant_share_percent
    ).aggregate(
        # Investments
        total_investment=Sum(
            applicant_amount,
            filter=Q(income_type='INVESTMENT'),
            output_field=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
        )
    )
```

I feel like maybe I need a SubQuery in there to pull only the percentage for the given client but I'm just not sure.

Comment: Is there something that isn't working? Could you show us what output you get vs the output you want?

Comment: @Swift I know the result is incorrect because there's no point where the `owners__percent` is limited to the specified applicant. I just can't figure out where to apply this filter so I get totals of income where the applicant has an equal share AND income where their share is specifically specified.